# ImportError: cannot import name <lib> python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run `tox -e coverage` in `python2.7` for the [ecdsa](https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa) library in Python.

The `src/ecdsa/util.py` file looks like:

```
import os
import math
import sys
import binascii
from hashlib import sha256
from . import der
from .curves import orderlen
```

However, when I run `tox -e coverage` I'm getting the following error:

```
________________________________ ERROR collecting src/ecdsa/test_numbertheory.py _________________________________
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
src/ecdsa/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .keys import (
src/ecdsa/keys.py:62: in <module>
    from . import ecdsa
src/ecdsa/ecdsa.py:59: in <module>
    from .util import bit_length
src/ecdsa/util.py:9: in <module>
    from . import der
E   ImportError: cannot import name der
```

What's the correct way to import these libraries in `python2.7`?

## Update:

So, inside `src/ecdsa/ecdsa.py` I have the following definition:

```
# NIST Curve P-192:
_p = 6277101735386680763835789423207666416083908700390324961279
_r = 6277101735386680763835789423176059013767194773182842284081
# s = 0x3045ae6fc8422f64ed579528d38120eae12196d5L
# c = 0x3099d2bbbfcb2538542dcd5fb078b6ef5f3d6fe2c745de65L
_b = 0x64210519E59C80E70FA7E9AB72243049FEB8DEECC146B9B1
_Gx = 0x188DA80EB03090F67CBF20EB43A18800F4FF0AFD82FF1012
_Gy = 0x07192B95FFC8DA78631011ED6B24CDD573F977A11E794811

curve_192 = ellipticcurve.CurveFp(_p, -3, _b)
generator_192 = ellipticcurve.Point(curve_192, _Gx, _Gy, _r)
```

and inside `src/ecdsa/curves.py` I have:

```
import der
import ecdsa
```

When I run `tox -e coverage` I'm getting the following error:

```
____________________________________ ERROR collecting src/ecdsa/test_ecdsa.py ____________________________________
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
src/ecdsa/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from keys import (
src/ecdsa/keys.py:62: in <module>
    import ecdsa
src/ecdsa/ecdsa.py:59: in <module>
    from util import bit_length
src/ecdsa/util.py:10: in <module>
    from curves import orderlen
src/ecdsa/curves.py:36: in <module>
    ecdsa.curve_192,
E   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'curve_192'
```

Comment: @cybertextron, have you tried directly `import der`?

Comment: @Christopher: I've updated my question ....